# How to store data into database using PyMYSQL in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pymysql

I am scraping a website and getting the companies details from it, Now I trying  to store the data into database. But I am getting some error like

```
raise InternalError(errno, errorvalue)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'companyaddress' in 'field list'")
```

Here is my code

```
for d in companydetail:
    lis = d.find_all('li')
    companyname = lis[0].get_text().strip()
    companyaddress = lis[1].get_text().strip()
    companycity = lis[2].get_text().strip()
try:
   companypostalcode = lis[3].get_text().strip()
   companypostalcode = companypostalcode.replace(",","")

except:
   companypostalcode = lis[3].get_text().strip()
try:
   companywebsite = lis[4].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
   companywebsite = 'null'
print (companyname)                          
print (companyaddress)
print (companycity)
print (companypostalcode)
print (companywebsite)
try:
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
   print ('saving to db')
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO company(companyname,address,city,pincode,website) VALUES (companyname,companyaddress,companycity,companypostalcode,companywebsite)")
   connection.commit()
   connection.close()
```

I am getting my data which I want but it I am not able to store data into database.
The result which I get while print (companyname) and print (campanyaddress) is :

```
NINGBO BOIGLE DIGITAL TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
TIANYUAN INDUSTRIAL ZONE CIXI NINGBO
ZHEJIANGNINGBO
315325
http://www.boigle.com.cn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use variable names inside a query string as you do:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO company(companyname,address,city,pincode,website) VALUES (companyname,companyaddress,companycity,companypostalcode,companywebsite)")
```

Instead, pass your variables into the query making it *parameterized*:

```
params = (companyname, companyaddress, companycity, companypostalcode, companywebsite)
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        company
        (companyname, address, city, pincode, website) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
""", params)
```

Comment: It worked only one time after that it gives error:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\new.py", line 112, in <module>
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 701, in close
    raise err.Error("Already closed")
pymysql.err.Error: Already closed

Comment: @SiteshRanjan yeah, cause you call the `connection.close()`.

Comment: @ alecxe. yes I have corrected it . But I am getting another error :
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 309
    self._do_get_result()
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBC\x8Cifl...' for column 'website' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

In

```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO company(companyname,address,city,pincode,website) VALUES (companyname,companyaddress,companycity,companypostalcode,companywebsite)")
```

the values in the second bracket are interpreted as table fields, rather than as python variables. Try

```
   cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO company(
           companyname,address,city,pincode,website) 
       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
       (companyname, companyaddress, companycity, 
        companypostalcode, companywebsite))
```

instead. You may also want to consult [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) on that.

Comment: Worked for only one time after that it gived error: 
[During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\new.py", line 112, in <module>
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 701, in close
    raise err.Error("Already closed")
pymysql.err.Error: Already closed]

Comment: Guess the indentation in teh question is wrong and the `cursor.execute()` is done within the iteration `for d in companydetail:`. In that case, simply move the `close()` and `commit()` calls outside that loop by de-indenting them.

Comment: Yes I have corrected it But I am getting another error :
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\amanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 309
    self._do_get_result()
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBC\x8Cifl...' for column 'website' at row 1

Comment: Please check the `collation` settings of the database you are using and also the `charset` of the web page you are scraping (in the `<head>` you will find a `Content-Type` `<meta>`).